# virtual vs pure virtual base class functions and exporting from dll

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a base class defined in a dll as below:

```
class Base
{
   public:
      virtual void doSomething(); // Definition in cpp
      virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0; // May have a definition in cpp
};
```

In another dll, I derive from Base and implement the necessary methods

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
     // Use base implementation for doSomething
     void doSomethingElse() override;
}
```

I am getting linker error unresolved external symbol for Base::doSomething().

From what I understand, since the doSomething()  was not overriden, the derived class needs access to the Base::doSomething definition which since I have not exported the Base class explicitly, is unavailable to derived which is in another module.

But why this problem doesn't happen with pure virtual function(it too could have a definition)?

**P.S** I am using VS2013

Comment: Why would you put a definition in the base's .cpp file for a function declared pure virtual in the header ? Can you clarify what you mean by "may have a definition" ? Would you then remove the `= 0` in the declaration ?

Comment: What if I want clients to override always, but they can use my common steps(base impl) as a precursor to their specific steps in derived

Comment: That's a bit strange. If there's a default implementation in the base class, why forcing the derived class to override it? If you want a preamble to be always executed, this calls for a public nonvirtual function to do the preamble and then calls a private pure virtual function. Derived classes then implement this private function, but can't call it directly since it's private to the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why this problem doesn't happen with pure virtual function(it too could have a definition)?

This would happen only if the pure virtual function of the base class is explicitly invoked. Otherwise, it is not necessary to be implemented.

E.g. Had you implemented `Derived::doSomethingElse()` as:

```
void Derived::doSomethingElse()
{
   // Do base class stuff first.
   Base::doSomethingElse();

   // Then do derived stuff
}
```

you would have seen the same problem for `Base::doSomethingElse` also.